# Removing border from bottom side of bar in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How would you get rid of the bottom border for a bar, but not all the borders for that particular bar? Example:

```
plt.broken_barh(
            [(uncertainty_tuples[i][3], low_width), (base_npv, high_width)],
            (i - 0.4, 0.8),
            facecolors=['#00B4FF','#00B4FF'], 
            edgecolors=['black', 'black'],
            linewidth=LINE_WIDTH
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach first plots the `broken_barh` and in a second pass draws black lines over 3 sides. To make sure the fourth line connects well with the others, the `broken_barh` is drawn with the same line thickness and with the edgecolor set to the facecolor.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

LINE_WIDTH = 5
for i in range(5):
    broken_barh_collection = plt.broken_barh(
        [(i * 10, 7), ((i + 1) * 10, 5), ((i + 2) * 10, 3)],
        (i - 0.4, 0.8),
        facecolors='#00B4FF',
        edgecolors='face',
        linewidth=LINE_WIDTH)
    for p in broken_barh_collection.get_paths():
        path = p.vertices
        plt.plot(path[:4, 0], path[:4, 1], color='black', linewidth=LINE_WIDTH)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]